# Get the Custom Fields value in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I use the Advanced Custom Fields plugin in wordpress. I have to get the value which i have store in the pages. Is there any function for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`get_field()`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/functions/get_field/) or [`the_field()`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/functions/the_field/).

You pass post meta name as the first parameter. You can optionally pass the associated post ID as second parameter.

Answer (score -1):

you can use this function [get_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta)
it accepts three arguments post id, meta key and single which Boolean and optional

or if you don't want to edit the template file just add these short code in the content part of the page or post. [for more information...](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/getting-started/displaying-custom-field-values-in-your-theme/)

```
[acf field="{$field_name}"]
[acf field="{$field_name}" post_id="{$post_id}"]
```